# Cant connect Database to WordPress

Tags: database, wordpress, sqlyog

I am failing to connect SQLYogUltimate database to Wordpress 4.5.1. Whenever I try to connect, I get the following error:

> This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at Localhost.

However all my credential of DB are correct.

Answer (score 0):

since you are sure of your databasename, username and password are all correct then it might be the localhost
sometimes internal networking can not map the local host to the 127.0.0.1, so in wp-config try to change the localhost to 127.0.0.1 and also make sure with your database service supplier if they have a specific IP for it.

Comment: Thanks! I have inserted the DB credentials in wp-config.php and changed the MySQL hostname  to the systems IPv4 address. Now I'm getting a page 
"Error establishing a database connection" .

I have setup local server using XAMPP and localhost is running perfect for other appilactions.

Comment: make sure that username have user privliges to the given database

Comment: Thanks Ahmad! found the problem. It appears using XAMPP, data is fetched from another server which I used for testing a web application. I have created a DB in that server and changed wp-config.php file. Its working now